# Screen scroll to top after clicked or selected a date in text field or calender

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

The screen scrolls back to the top after clicked/right clicked on both of the date text field, or the calender. Wondering why is this happening. 
Can someone help me troubleshoot this?
Thank you so much!

HTML codes:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
<table border="0">
<tr style="height: 40px">
<td style="width: 80px">Start Date</td>
<td>
<div class="input-group date" id="datepicker">
<input id="startDate" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="list_S_date_Selected">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="0">
<tr style="height: 40px">
<td style="width: 80px">End Date</td>
<td>
<div class="input-group date" id="datepicker2">
<input id="endDate" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="list_E_date_Selected">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
</span>
</div>
</td>
</table>
</li>
```

The Javascript:

```
$(function() {
var today_Date = new Date();
$('#datepicker')
.datepicker({
startDate: document.getElementById("startDate").value,
endDate: new Date(), 
autoclose: true,
format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
})

.on('changeDate', function(selected){                       
var startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));

var ToEndDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
ToEndDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()+30); //89

if(ToEndDate >= today_Date){
$('#datepicker2').datepicker('setEndDate', new Date());
$('#datepicker2').datepicker('setDate', new 

Date(today_Date.getFullYear(), today_Date.getMonth(), today_Date.getDate()));
}else {
$('#datepicker2').datepicker('setEndDate', ToEndDate);
$('#datepicker2').datepicker('setDate', ToEndDate);
};
});
```

Comment: Can you make fiddle? Your code seems fine!

Comment: Haha, thank you for your feedback! It works already! :D